# shell_exec and exec functions can not produce an output file

Tags: php, bash, curl

I have a server and client. Server has a php file. Here it is:

```
$postdata = $_FILES['request'];
$reqContent= file_get_contents($postdata['tmp_name']);
shell_exec("echo ".$reqContent." > request.txt");
```

I sent a file from client to server with this command :

```
curl -i -F "request=@example.txt" <server_url>
```

But output file(request.txt) can not created.How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Run it as the web user and find out: `sudo -u www-data echo ".$reqContent." > request.txt`

Comment: Variable `$reqContent` contains file data?? Try printing this variable. If has value you could use then `file_put_contents()` method.

Comment: Yes it contains file data but file_put_contents() didn't work  @alvk4r

Comment: There seems to be a major security problem with this current setup

Comment: @MikeB i tried it but didn't work

Comment: Why didn't work?? Give me error info. Apache user must have write permissions on the directory where you are putting your file. Before `file_put_contents` try `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /directory` and `sudo chmod -R 775 /directory`. Execute on console not from php script. Then you can try file_put_contents

Answer (score 1):

Check your webserver error logs to verify that your not getting an error like 'permission denied' when you test that.

Also you might try `shell_exec('pwd')` and a `shell_exec('whoami')` and check the permissions on that directory to verify that the webserver user that is executing the command has permission to write there.